# How to navigate to the type under the cursor in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

In Eclipse control + left click navigate to the place where the type is defined (also navigates to declaration of variable). How do I achieve the action same without the mouse when I am placed with cursor on the word? (Without using control + shift + T).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

button `F3` . here is a good article about [Eclipse Shortcuts](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseShortcuts/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the type name, just press F3.

Answer (score 0):

Place the cursor on the variable or method and Just Press F3